# How to count specific value from array PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, count

I have an multidimensional array and I need to count their specific value

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
      [Report] => Array
        (
         [id] => 10
         [channel] => 1
         )
     )

    [1] => Array
      (
       [Report] => Array
         (
           [id] => 92
           [channel] => 0
         )
      )

    [2] => Array
      (
         [Report] => Array
         (
            [id] => 18
            [channel] => 0
         )
      )
    [n] => Array
)
```

I need to get output like that: channel_1 = 1; channel_0 = 2 etc

I made a function with foreach:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
  echo $item['Report']['channel'];
}
```

and I get: 1 0 0 ... but how can I count it like: channel_1 = 1; channel_0 = 2, channel_n = n etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. See comments for step-by-step explanation.
Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  ["channel_1"]=>
  int(1)
  ["channel_0"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Code:

```
<?php

// Your input array.
$a =
[
    [
        'Report' =>
        [
            'id' => 10,
            'channel' => 1
        ]
    ],
    [
        'Report' =>
        [
            'id' => 92,
            'channel' => 0
        ]
    ],
    
    [
        'Report' =>
        [
            'id' => 18,
            'channel' => 0
        ]
    ]
];

// Output array will hold channel_N => count pairs
$result = [];

// Loop over all reports
foreach ($a as $report => $values)
{
    // Key takes form of channel_ + channel number
    $key = "channel_{$values['Report']['channel']}";
    
    if (!isset($result[$key]))
        // New? Count 1 item to start.
        $result[$key] = 1;
    else
        // Already seen this, add one to counter.
        $result[$key]++;
}

var_dump($result);
/*
Output:
array(2) {
  ["channel_1"]=>
  int(1)
  ["channel_0"]=>
  int(2)
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this without a loop using [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and `array_count_values()`.

```
$reports = array_column($array, 'Report');
$channels = array_column($reports, 'channel');
$counts = array_count_values($channels);
```

`$counts` will now equal an array where the key is the channel, and the value is the count.

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [0] => 2
)
```

Comment: Thanks Grumpy as well!

Comment: @Vova No problem.